# Notification when client doesn't completes the payment in Paypal

Tags: paypal

I am developing a website for a holiday home using Paypal as payment method. The booking system works as follow:

1. Once the client selects the dates and clicks on "buy now" the selected dates get "reserved" for the client so no one else can select them during the payment process.
2. Once the payment is done, IPN triggers a PHP script to change the dates from "reserved" to "booked" (or "available" if the payment failed").

My problem is, how do I know if, once the client is redirected to the Paypal website, he/her changed his/her mind and just simply closes the browser? I need to know so I can make those dates available again but I can't find anything in the IPN documentation or Paypal developers site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't involve the IPN script itself but the application your developing.

It would be best to have a time limit on how long a date can be reserved before it is returned back to available. PayPal's session time-limit is 15 minutes so if PayPal is the only payment option you can run a cron job every 30 minutes or longer to change the status of the dates from "reserved" to "available"

- Once a date is selected place it into "reserved" status
- If a successful IPN is received change the dates to "booked" or if no IPN is received within 30 minutes have a cron job run to update the status.

Comment: I thought about that option... So PayPal session last only for 15 min? Is that time of "inactivity"?

Comment: It's been a while since I tested this however I was incorrect on the session time frame. From the moment the user is directed to PayPal they have 30 minutes of active/inactive time to complete payment. Unfortunately waiting on PayPal wouldn't be an option as we don't send notifications of uncompleted payments.